# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a invalid content was found starting with element factory in faces-config.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf-2.2, faces-config

I have this error in a eclipse project, imported from a **`Netbeans`** project, set as a **`maven`** and project facet to **`Dynamic Web Project`** ( CDI1.1, Java 1.8, JS 1.0, JSF 2.2, JAX-RS 2.0, JBoss Maven Integration 1.0 and JPA 2.1)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>Messages</base-name>
            <var>messages</var>
        </resource-bundle>


         <factory>
            <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory> 
        </factory>

    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question, no node `factory` is allowed under the node `application` according to the `XSD` file http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd such that your `XML` file is invalid.

The list of supported elements under `application` is:

- action-listener
- default-render-kit-id
- message-bundle
- navigation-handler
- view-handler
- state-manager
- el-resolver
- property-resolver
- variable-resolver
- resource-handler
- resource-library-contracts
- system-event-listener
- locale-config
- resource-bundle
- application-extension
- default-validators

According to the `XSD` file, The node `factory` seems to be expected at the same level as `application` so directly under `faces-config` as next:

```
<faces-config ...
    <application>
    ...
    </application>
     <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory> 
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```